# Spring Boot YAML config for directory tree structure - what class to use?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I would like to specify a general file/directory tree structure in a Spring Boot application.yaml file:

```
spring.datasource.url: "jdbc:mysql://localhost/test"

myapp.source:
  dir1:
    dir1a:
      file1:
      file2:
  dir2:
    file3:
    file4:
```

What sort of class can I use with `@ConfigurationProperties("myapp.source")` to load this configuration?  It seems like it would be a recursive "Map of Maps" of some kind?

Comment: Is the number of dirs and files variable/arbitrary? In other words, can there be more or less than you're showing?

Comment: @E-Riz yes, arbitrarily broad and deep (and different for every use case of this app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're OK with the YAML structure like this:

```yaml
myapp:
  source:
    directories:
      - name: dir1
        directories:
          - name: dir1a
            files:
              - file1
              - file2
      - name: dir2
        files:
          - file3
          - file4
```

Then these classes can represent the structure:

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@ConfigurationProperties("myapp.source")
@Configuration
public class SourceProperties {

    private List<Directory> directories;
}
```

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class Directory {

    private String name;
    private List<Directory> directories;
    private List<String> files;
}
```

This is what the `SourceProperties` looks like built from that yaml:
[image]

Depending on your needs, those classes can have various methods. Could even make the files an object (instead of `String`) if you need more info about them.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative would be to have the YAML like this:

```yaml
myapp:
  source:
    dir1:
      directories:
        dir1a:
          files:
           - file1
           - file2
    dir2:
      files:
        - file3
        - file4
      directories:
        dir2a:
          files:
            - file5
```

And the classes like this:

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@ConfigurationProperties("myapp")
@Configuration
public class SourceProperties {
    private Map<String, Directory> source;
}


@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class Directory {
    private Map<String, Directory> directories;
    private List<String> files;
}
```

Comment: I like this one, but it doesn't look like it handles an empty top level directory, like `myapp/source/dir1`

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't handle?"